# PHP sends an empty Response Payload instead of JSON

Tags: php, json, ajax, get

Sorry if I'm not good at formulating questions or if this isn't a good question, but I've been trying for days and getting no progress on this and I'm ready to effing cry. Please, please help.

So this PHP file:

```
<?php

 header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8"); 
 
 $obj = json_decode($_GET["x"], true);
 $conn = new mysqli("localhost", "user", "password", "database");
 $i = 1;
 $message = array();
 
 while ($i < 31){
     
     $query = $conn->prepare("SELECT dag, maand, jaar, timeslot FROM boeker WHERE dag = $i AND maand = ? AND jaar = ?");
     $query->bind_param('ii', $obj["monthQ"], $obj["yearQ"]);
     $query->execute();
     $result = $query->get_result();
     $outp = $result->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
     $message = array();     
     
     if(empty($result)){
         //available
     } else if ($result["timeslot"] == null){
         array_push($message, "occupied", $i);
     } else {
         array_push($message, $result["timeslot"], $i);
     }
     $i++;
 }
 
 $package = json_encode($message);
 echo $package;
 
?>
```

is getting this request:

> https://url/file.php?x='{"monthQ":10,"yearQ":2021}'

and the reply is an empty Response Payload, which throws an error, because it can't be JSON.parsed

I would think that $message, even when the array stays empty, would make $package a simple [], which should parse...

Is something wrong with my PHP?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Does it definitely return a 200 OK response? Not some other http code?

Comment: Just double-checked, yessir, HTTP response 200

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the single quotes around the json string in your url. If you have no control over constructing that url, you can just run:

```
$obj = json_decode(trim($_GET['x'],"'"), true);
```

I've tested that, and it works.

If you do have control over constructing that url, I recommend that you remove the single quotes AND urlencode the json block.

Comment: Also, you want to move `$message = array();` to before the `while` or you will ever have only one item in it, maybe empty.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I've removed the single quotes and used encodeURIComponent to encode the json. The response is still empty, but now the HTTP response is 500, so that's good I guess, 'cause that tells me a bit more... 
(and i've removed the double $message initiator, thanks :) ) Still no succes though

Comment: Start by commenting out the `header(...` line and adding: 
`ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
`
so you can see what the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

Leaving breadcrumbs after solving a similar problem here.  My php.ini file had a max_post_size set to 2K and I was sending a POST request with size >2K.  PHP decided to sweep the problem under the rug and proceed with the request with an empty body.